# Python - intersection of curves causes identification between them

Tags: python, scipy, precision

I have a function of two variables - f(x,y). I want to run on various values of y, and for each value of y, find the first n roots of f(x,y) (as a function of a single variable). Then, I'd like to draw a graph which displays how roots change place as y changes (so y is the horizontal axis, and the curves represent the position of the different roots). When I did this, I got the following graph:
[image]

As you can see, the graph has some sudden bumps which arise simultaneously for all curves (and from what I know about the function f, these bumps should not exist). Notice that these bumps happen whenever two curves are about to intersect. I concluded that the reason for these bumps appearing is as follows:

Whenever two roots get very close to one another (meaning, for some y, the two root curves are about to intersect), they get identified as the same root (to find the roots, I use the method of bisection on small intervals using scipy's root_scalar function, but if the roots are very close, then the method cannot recognize both). When this happens, this causes a 'shift' in the graphs - the numbering of the roots changes, and so the curves can switch place with one another (so the bumps are actually due to a root curve going into the position of a different root curve).

I was wondering if anyone has an idea on how to solve this. I thought about making the interval for bisection smaller, but if the root curves intersect, this wouldn't help (since the roots get arbitrarily close). I also thought about setting the size of the intervals for bisection to be dependent on the previously documented distance between the roots - if on the last iteration I had two roots that are 0.2 apart, then on the next root finding iteration (for the next value of y) I'll set the size of the intervals to be 0.1, so that I can still tell them apart. But this causes the process to not converge - I look at smaller and smaller intervals and the process doesn't terminate.

I'd also like to present this question a bit more generally. When computing two curves (which are not distinct functions, but actually depend on one another, like my case of two consecutive roots of a function), is there a method to avoid the two curves being 'identified' when the two curves intersect? How can I keep telling them apart?

I'd be happy to hear any idea. I'm also attaching the part of the code which finds the roots, to convey what's going on (I then simply repeat this process for many different values of y to obtain the given curves). If you have any further questions please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

```
def secroots(s, l): # s is the value of y, l is the number of roots I want to find
    roots=[]
    delta=0.01 #this will be the size of the intervals for biscetion
    i=0.01 #this is where I start looking for roots
    while (len(roots)<(l)):
        c = secdet(i, s) #secdet is the function f(x,y)
        d = secdet(i+delta, s)
        if c*d<0:
            x = optimize.root_scalar(lambda a: secdet(a,s), bracket=[i, i+delta], method='bisect')
            if x.converged:
                roots.append(x.root)
        i=i+delta
    return roots
```